# How to get confirmation when calendar event was created via intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, calendar

I'm creating a calendar event via intent. Here is my code:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Calendar event")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, " This is a calendar event " + activity().getCallHistoryItem().getCaller())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Location")
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, activity().getCallHistoryItem().getCaller());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

on the onClick() of a button, this intent starts and the calendar app starts as expected. My question is, is there a way to get confirmation the user created the event? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a BroadcastReceiver to receive change events from the default Android calendar by creating a BroadcastReceiver with the following intent filter:

```
 <receiver
   android:name=".NativeEventChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note that no information is passed along with this receiver - you'll need to query the calendar API upon receipt of that to find what has changed. If you are doing an operation that may take a long time, you may want to consider using a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html)  and an  [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to do the longer running process (as BroadcastReceivers must complete within 10 seconds as per the  [onReceive() documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29)).